# Can ricotta be made with UHT milk?

Tags: cheese

I live in an area where ricotta cheese is non existent, and all the dairy products I have access to are high temp pasteurized. Will that work?  Are there any herbs in ricotta? I'm trying to make my lasagna without it, and it would just would not be the same.

Comment: "high temp pasteurized" like in UHT ? if that is so, you are out of luck; I'm surprised you cannot find regular pasteurized milk?

Comment: Agreed that it's a duplicate.  Vincent, see the linked answer.  You can make a ricotta-like cheese with UHT milk (but not most other cheeses).

Comment: It seems that the body of the question indeed asks about the use of UHT (= "high temp pasteurized") milk, so I changed the title and closed. If the question was for a recipe for making your own ricotta, I am afraid we do not swap recipes. A simple search on the Internet found 400 000 results, and all on the first page were recipes, so you shouldn't have trouble finding one.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there are not herbs in ricotta, but there's nothing preventing you to add herb to it, I do it all the time when using it on toasts; and would be acceptable for a lasagna.